# Is there a large compilation of bad or naughty words availiable so I can filter them out in my front-end app using JavaScript?

Tags: library, javascript, typescript

Looking for a npm front-end library for my Angular 11 app I can use to filter out bad words. Below is a function that does it, but I would hate if I have to compile my own list of words as there are a great many bad and naughty words.

```
function filterBadWords(inputString) {
  const badWords = ["badword1", "badword2", "badword3"]; 
  const pattern = new RegExp(badWords.join("|"), "gi");
  const filteredString = inputString.replace(pattern, "****");

  return filteredString;
}
```

I'm not in need of the code to do it, the code works fine, but a giant list of words, a word bank that I can pull from to check for bad words.

The app I'm creating involves making a sparql to wikiservice and sometimes there are bad words or naughty words that come back. For example, I sometimes get back a list of celebrities and there occupations. Well sometimes I get back "pornographic model" or worse. Do I really have to compile my own list of words? Is there a front end library I can use? This is for a front end application.

Comment: Perhaps there is. But its very subjective.

Comment: A good read on this to give you insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter